# Rails form changing number of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails, I have a UserOffer model, that has_many Steps.
When I create a new UserOffer instance, I want that form to include a dropdown that says “select number of steps of that UserOffer”. Based on the number of steps selected (n), I want the form to expand, and include n extra fields, called “step 1 title”, “step 2 title” … “step n title”.
I figured I need to use nested attributed to do this, but I wanted to know how the form would look like, preferably without using JS or Ajax (just with RoR).
I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that, at the same form without refreshing the page, you will need to use an ajax request to the server, in order to add the steps to the UserOffer model. Remember that RoR only let you do things on the render step of the DOM, in other words, if you had rendered the form you will not be able to do another changes on the page without use javascript.